# Sencha Touch 2 - Android Packaging errors

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm trying to package my Sencha Touch 2 based mobile application for Android. Followed the steps mentioned at the [Sencha documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/guide/native_android), always getting some different errors.

None of these commands works: *(added errors below of each command)*

```
$ sencha package build packager.json
[ERR] Command must be run from a package folder
$ sencha package run packager.json
[ERR] Unknown command: "run"
$ sencha package packager.json
[ERR] Unknown command: "packager.json"
```

After I googled this situation; found an answer that says valid command is:

```
$ sencha app package build packager.json
```

**Getting these errors:**

```
Copy operation failed src=st-res/android//nimblekit.jar dst=build///libs/nimblekit.jar
Can not open source file
Failed to copy packager library
Failed to package application
```

**Environment & Tool Details:**

**OS :** Linux

**Sencha Touch version :** 2.2.1

**Sencha Cmd version :** 3.1.2.342

Answer (score 2):

Following are steps to create Sencha android build:

1. Create certificate using keytool command for signing android application:

   > keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name
   >        -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

   it will create keystore for you.
2. Open 'packager.json' file & make following changes:

   - Give application id like bundle id eg: 'com.abcd.appname'
   - change platform to 'Android' or 'AndroidEmulator'
   - then give certification path: i.e. path to your newly created keystore.
   - give your 'certificate alias' & 'certificate password'.
   - give your android 'sdkPath'
   - Also set 'androidAPILevel'. To find list of android api levels or targets, 
     goto **sdk-path/tools** and hit **./android list target** command
3. Copy **'st-res'** folder from your **sencha cmd directory(for linux: /home/bin/Sencha/Cmd/ur-version-name/stbuild) to your project directory.**
4. then run command:

   > sencha app build native
5. It will create **.apk** file to output folder which you have set in 'packager.json' file.

Hope this will help you. But my opinion is you use Phonegap for packaging the app. You can build app using Sencha touch & just use Phonegap to deploy app to android or iOS.

Comment: followed same steps, getting these errors: `[ERR] Please ensure this command was executed from a valid application directory`
`[ERR] Unable to locate 'app.dir' config property from sencha.cfg`

Answer (score 0):

Sencha.cfg is created by Sencha Cmd, so:

did you generate the app by Sencha Cmd: sencha generate app?
If not rename your app folder. Create the app with Sencha Cmd and copyright the content from the renamed folder to the created folder.
Then try again.

Comment: Just applied your recommendations; now getting error I added below. By the way, I create my application without Sencha Cmd, it's a maven based Java web application. But I copied .sencha folder after I created a new touch application with same name. Also I'm getting same error when I try to package this new application created by Sencha Cmd. Here is the full error stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/CJbcJbCV